# Indecomposable module decomposition with idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am a bit confused with something and I feel a bit stupid.

Let $\Lambda$ be a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $K$. Let $M$ be a right $\Lambda$-module and let $e$ be an idempotent in $\Lambda$, different from $0$ and $1$. Then
$$ M\cdot 1 = M \cdot (e+1-e) = Me+M(1-e)= Me\oplus M(1-e)$$
where the sum is direct, since if we have $me=m'(1-e)$ for some $m,m'\in M$ then $me-m'e=m'$ hence $me=(me-m'e)(1-e)$ whence $me=me-me-m'e+m'e=0$ and so $me=0$.

In particular, if $M$ is indecomposable, we must either have $Me=0$ or $M(1-e)=0$. Now take $\Lambda$ to be the algebra of upper triangular $3\times 3$ matrices. There is a unique $3$-dimensional indecomposable $\Lambda$-module, namely
$$M = \{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b,c\in K\},$$
where multiplication with elements of $\Lambda$ is defined by usual matrix multiplication. Take $e=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $1-e =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $Me=\{(a,0,0) \mid a\in K\}$ and $M(1-e)=\{(0,b,c)\mid b,c\in K\}$. In particular $Me\neq 0$ and $M(1-e)\neq 0$ and so $M$ is not indecomposable.

I have spent quite some time trying to find the simple mistake in the above reasoning but I failed...

Comment: You can check that $Me$ and $M(1-e)$ are not modules, hence not submodules of $M$.

Comment: So the decomposition $M=Me\oplus M(1-e)$ is only as a vector space in general?

Comment: Yes, it is only a decomposition of vector spaces.

Comment: @Stacy Are you confusing it with this fact?: Every direct decomposition of $M_\lambda$ is of the form $e(M)\oplus (1-e)(M)$ where $e$ is an idempotent of $End(M_\lambda)$. That endomorphism ring will only have trivial idempotents iff $M$ is directly irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $xe=y(1-e)$, then $xe=xe^2=y(1-e)e=0$. However, you need that $Me$ and $M(1-e)$ are submodules, which generally isn't true.

It is true if $e$ is a central idempotent, so also $\Lambda$ is a direct sum $\Lambda e\oplus\Lambda(1-e)$ of algebras; in this case it's almost obvious that an indecomposable $\Lambda$-module must be either an indecomposable $\Lambda e$-module or an indecomposable $\Lambda(1-e)$-module.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now!